# SQL Server xml.modify delete method

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a problem with removing an attribute from a node.

Example:

```sql
DECLARE @processID int
SET @processID = 8

DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = 
'<Process id="10" name="Test 1">
  <Shapes>
    <Shape id="1" name="Shape 1" subProcessID="8">
    </Shape>
    <Shape id="2" name="Shape 2" subProcessID="9">
    </Shape>
  </Shapes>
  <Lines />
</Process>'

SET @xml.modify('delete (/Process/Shapes/Shape/@subProcessID[/Process/Shapes/Shape/@subProcessID = sql:variable("@processID")])')
SELECT @xml
```

Gives the result:

```xml
<Process id="10" name="Test 1">
  <Shapes>
    <Shape id="1" name="Shape 1" />
    <Shape id="2" name="Shape 2" />
  </Shapes>
  <Lines />
</Process>
```

What I would like is:

```xml
<Process id="10" name="Test 1">
  <Shapes>
    <Shape id="1" name="Shape 1" />
    <Shape id="2" name="Shape 2" subProcessID="9" />
  </Shapes>
  <Lines />
</Process>
```

What is the syntax to achieve this?

Comment: I found the solution:

SET @xml.modify('delete (/Process/Shapes/Shape[@subProcessID = sql:variable("@processID")]/@subProcessID)')

Does the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

As the OP is gone but he left the solution in a comment let me add that as an answer:

```
DECLARE @processID int
SET @processID = 8

DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = 
'<Process id="10" name="Test 1">
  <Shapes>
    <Shape id="1" name="Shape 1" subProcessID="8">
    </Shape>
    <Shape id="2" name="Shape 2" subProcessID="9">
    </Shape>
  </Shapes>
  <Lines />
</Process>'

SET @xml.modify('delete (/Process/Shapes/Shape[@subProcessID = sql:variable("@processID")]/@subProcessID)')
SELECT @xml
```

Here is [a working sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26925) for that.